# ¿Cómo hacer que un botón no se salga de su elemento padre?

Tags: html, css, responsive

Mi `header` utiliza iconos y un botón de login, lo personalice en su momento en base a las dimensiones de mi pantalla colocando los íconos al margen derecho mediante la propiedad `margin-left` lo cual ahora me trae problemas para probar si es responsive. En su momento pensé que se vería bien pero no tuve en cuenta el diseño responsive como les mencionaba y ahora me encuentro en el problema de qué mis íconos se desbordan hacia la derecha y más precisamente el botón de `acceder` que sobresale del `header` dónde tendrían que estar contenido al icual que todos los elementos dentro del encabezado. Además de qué se desbordan la pantalla se extiende hacia los costados debido a que los posicione mal desde un principio.

¿Cómo puedo hacer mi header sea responsive sin qué se desborden mis elementos hacia los costados?

Ejemplo del fallo

[image: ad]

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? family=Roboto:wght@700&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 550;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #292f33;
}


/* ------------- SCROLLBAR ------------- */

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 1.5px;
  width: 6.5px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #e0e0e0;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #acacac;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
}


/* ------------- ELIMINAR SUBRAYADO ------------- */

a:link,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.grid-container>* {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 5px;
  grid-template: "header" 70px "main" auto "navbar" 50px "footer" 100px;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template: "navbar header" 65px "main  main" auto "footer  footer" 100px / 200px auto;
  }
  .main .row3 {
    max-height: 35vh;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template: "navbar  header  header" 55px "main    main    main" auto "footer  footer  footer" 100px / 200px auto 200px;
  }
  .main .row3 {
    max-height: 35vh;
  }
}


/* -----------------  ENCABEZADO  ----------------- */

.header {
  padding-top: 1.2%;
  grid-area: header;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background: #5a415a;
  border-left: 2.5px solid #EEE7CE;
  border-bottom: 2.5px solid #EEE7CE;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.header .logo {
  display: inline-flex;
  font-size: 1.35rem;
  font-weight: 450;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.header .logo i {
  display: inline-flex;
  color: #a800a8;
  font-size: 1.9rem;
}

.header .logoLupa {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin-left: 55%;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

.header .logoHeart {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin-left: 3%;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  margin-top: -.3%;
}

.header .icons div,
.header .icons a {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline;
}

.header .icons div:hover,
.header .icons a:hover {
  color: #FFC728;
}

.header .menu-button {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 170%;
  margin-top: -15%;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: transparent;
}

.header .right-menu {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.header .dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #EEE7CE;
  min-width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.header .dropdown-menu a {
  color: #000000;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.header .dropdown-menu a:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #EEE7CE;
}

.header .right-menu:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.header .right-menu:hover .menu-button {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.header .btn-warning {
  background-color: #f08370;
  margin-left: 90%;
  margin-top: -5%;
  border-color: #f08370;
}

.header .btn-warning:hover {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-color: #ff4828;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- ===== Iconscout CSS ===== -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css">
  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="newstyleBox.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
</head>

<body class="grid-container">
  <!----------- ENCABEZADO ----------->
  <header class="header">
    <a href="/" class="logo"> <i class="uil uil-book-alt"></i> Biblioteca</a>



    <!-- SE DESBORDAN DEL BORDE DERECHO AL PROBAR RESPONSIVE -->
    <a href="/exploreBooksPublic" class="logoLupa"> <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i></a>

    <a href="#" class="logoHeart"> <i class="uil uil-heart"></i></a>

    <div class="loggedin">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="right-menu">
          <a class="btn btn-warning" href="/login" role="button">Acceder</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible solución para hacer que el header sea responsive es utilizar la propiedad flex en lugar de margin-left para posicionar los íconos en la parte derecha del header. Aquí te muestro un ejemplo de cómo podrías modificar tu CSS para hacerlo:

```
.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.header .logo {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}

.header .loggedin {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header .right-menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header .dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 10rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  margin: 0.125rem 0 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #212529;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.header .dropdown-menu a {
  color: #000000;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.header .dropdown-menu a:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #EEE7CE;
}

.header .right-menu:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.header .right-menu:hover .menu-button {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.header .btn-warning {
  background-color: #f08370;
  border-color: #f08370;
}

.header .btn-warning:hover {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-color: #ff4828;
}

.header .logoLupa,
.header .logoHeart {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

En este CSS, utilizamos la propiedad display: flex en el header para que los elementos dentro de él se posicionen en línea. Luego, utilizamos la propiedad justify-content: space-between para que los elementos dentro del header se distribuyan de manera equitativa en el espacio disponible, y align-items: center para centrar los elementos verticalmente. De esta manera, los elementos se mantendrán dentro del header sin desbordarse hacia los costados. Además, eliminamos las propiedades de margin-left en los íconos y el botón de login y utilizamos margin en su lugar para darles un espacio uniforme.